# For each loop in Java with word count

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, foreach

I have a long text which is stored in a `String` (i.e. `tstr1` im code). Now I want to store the user input from console in a `String[]` (i.e. `itemsFromArray` im code).

I want for each word stored in the user input String[] array, the system to show how many times that word is present in the long Text String[] array. I tried in this way, but the problem is that the system shows the count just for first entry from an array but for the next it is showing zero.

```
  btnNewButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            keyW = txtKeyword.getText();
            search = textField.getText();
            System.out.println("String for car = " + search); 
            System.out.println("String keyword = " + keyW); 

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + search);
        tstr1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']")).getText();

        String [] itemsFromArray = keyW.split(",");  
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (String word : itemsFromArray){
            map.put(word, 0);
        }
         Scanner s = new Scanner(tstr1);
        while (s.hasNext()){
            String word = s.next();
            if (map.containsKey(word)){
                map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1);
                System.out.println("Word1 '" + word + "' count:" + map.get(word));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Word2 '" + word + "' not in map");
            }
        }

        driver.close();  
        }   
    });
```

Comment: You may want to use a `Map<String, Integer>` (word->count).

Comment: iterate over the input string and store the count (for each word) in a map where the word is the key and the value is the count.

Comment: I don't really understand how to do this, can you please explain in more detail. Thanks!!!

Comment: @DanPaschevici I've added some basic code. It's not tested but it should get you going. Let me know if it has errors.

Comment: If you want to be super efficient, you can use the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) which is designed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably better to use a `Map<String, Integer>`:

```
// initialize a mapping that is used to map words to their count   
Map<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

// initialize all counts to 0
for (String word : itemsFromArray){
    counter.put(word, 0);
}

// ...

// count words that are in map (give up those that aren't)
while (s.hasNext()){
    String word = s.next();
    if (counter.containsKey(word)){
        counter.put(word, counter.get(word) + 1);
        System.output.println("Word '" + word + "' count:" + counter.get(word));
    } else {
        System.output.println("Word '" + word + "' not in map");
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Sharabani, it's showing anything else, but the keywords that I set is not showing.  But I added above `while` the `Scanner s = new Scanner(tstr1);`.

Comment: It's not meant to deal with initialization, just shows you how to use a mapping to count words. I left everything outside that scope out.

Comment: Look, every word from that text is showing including just first keyword from my array, how to make to show just all keywords from array???

Comment: Add your attempt to your question

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Can you add the output you're expecting to see?

Comment: Yes, the output should be just the strings from `itemsFromArray` with their count (how many times are presented in `String keyW`). But now the output is counting all words from `String keyW`. The system is counting all words from the text, but I want just those who are in the array.

Comment: Words that are not in the array are never added to the map. So it's impossible for them to be counted. Perhaps the array itself already contains words you don't want?

Comment: Look, in the array I have 3 word (car, engine, year). I want that output should look like: word car is presented in `String keyW` 10 times. word engine is presented in `String keyW` 4 times and word year is presented in `String keyW` 21 times.

Answer (score 1):

After I spent one day, the problem was that when I tried to separate the string (without comma) and insert into array, the first string was good but the next started with white spaces and the system does not recognize the word.

```
    btnNewButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //If the button UPLOAD was not pressed we should to clear the ArrayList
            listKeys.clear();
            //////////////////////////////////////////////

            if(textField.getText().equals("")) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Make sure you enter at least one search key"); 

            }

       else if (txtKeyword.getText().equals("")) {

           System.out.println("String is NULL ");

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Add at least one keyword"); 
       } else {

            keyW = txtKeyword.getText();
            search = textField.getText();
            System.out.println("String for car = " + search); 
            System.out.println("String keyword = " + keyW); 

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + search);
        tstr1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']")).getText();

        String [] items = keyW.split(","); 
        String [] itemsFromArray = new String[items.length];
        for ( int i = 0; i <  items.length; i++)
        {
            itemsFromArray[i] = items[i].trim();
        }
            for(String string : itemsFromArray)
        {       
            //if (args[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(­ "from:" )) 

            System.out.println("FOREACH " + string);
            int i = countWords(tstr1, string);
            System.out.println("Word count "+ string + ":  " + i);
            Keyword1 = ("Count for word " + string + " are " + i);
            listKeys.add(Keyword1);
        }
    driver.close();   
    }   

        }




private static int countWords(String tstr1, String string)
    {   
        int i = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(tstr1);

        while (s.hasNext()) 
        {
            if (s.next().equals(string)) 
                i++;

        }

        return i;
    }
}
```